# No extents were found for the plex, when setting up Soft RAID 1 with RAID 5 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, raid, windows-server-2012, raid-1, raid-5

I did find a similar question on this, but it did not really answer my question or fix the problem, so i'm starting up a new questions on it.

This is my setup now:

[image: http://prntscr.com/7lktrn]

You can see if i have RAID 5 setup, that i run all my files on, then a boot partition at 50 GB, i want to RAID 1 the boot partition in the other unallocated section on disk 0 and disk 1, however when i try and add a mirror, i just get "No extents were found for the plex".

This is a production / in-use server, so reformatting is not really a solution. 
You can see the sizes are correct 48.83GB, so it's not a space issue.

If its not possible to fix this, without reformatting, what would happen if Disk 2 (which has my boot partition) on it broke? Would i be able to re-build the boot (i understand i would lose what is on the boot partition), and recover my files in RAID 5?

I understand that if Disk 0 broke, i would be fine, and be able to rebuild the RAID 5. But as my boot is not mirrored, im not sure what would happen if the disk 2, my boot and raid 5 disk broke.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with your Disk 2 failure question - in that situation you would just need to reinstall Windows so you have a working machine and plug in the working disks because it is a software RAID and each disk has its own MBR. Any version of Windows that supports software RAID would recognize the RAID 5. It would of course show degraded because you only have 2 of the 3 disks of the RAID 5 functioning. At that point you would want to copy off your data immediately or add a new disk to the RAID 5 and let it rebuild. You should always have a safe backup of your data anyway.

For the second question, I am not sure the reason, but it might be the case that the mirror RAID 1 that includes the boot partition and part of another disk would need to be created first. Right now, the RAID 5 was created before. I base this on comments I read here - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6f486437-bc12-41f5-8967-ca90e584e586/server-2008-disk-mirror-no-extents-were-found-for-the-plex
There likely could be other reasons though too.